# Mask values that occur less than K times in a pandas column (case insensitive comparison)

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I want to search an entire column 'Warehouse' in a Pandas Data Frame using Python and if a cell value occurs more than 3 times, I want to write the same value to the GeneralDescription column. I am trying to write code that would work for thousands of rows and ignore upper or lower case values. Here is my code that tries to accomplish this which only outputs the values that appear more than 3 times but does not write anything to the GeneralDescription column. What am I doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np

data= [[2,'Empty','Empty'],[3,'General Liability','Empty'],[4,'WRS','Empty'],[5,'WRS','Empty'],[6,'CENTRAL','Empty'],[7,'General Liability','Empty'],[8,'CENTRAL','Empty'],[9,'wrs','Empty'],[10,'WRS','Empty'],[11,'GENERAL LIABILITY','Empty'],[12,'General Liability','Empty']]
df1=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['LineNum','Warehouse','GeneralDescription'])

vc=df1.Warehouse.value_counts()
#print (vc[vc>3].index[0])

counts=Counter(df1.Warehouse.str.lower())
df1[df1.Warehouse.str.lower().isin([key for key in counts if counts[key]>3])].fillna(df1['GeneralDescription'])
```

df1

```
    LineNum Warehouse           GeneralDescription
0   2       Empty               Empty
1   3       General Liability   Empty
2   4       WRS                 Empty
3   5       WRS                 Empty
4   6       CENTRAL             Empty
5   7       General Liability   Empty
6   8       CENTRAL             Empty
7   9       wrs                 Empty
8  10       WRS                 Empty
9  11       GENERAL LIABILITY   Empty
10 12       General Liability   Empty
```

df2 Desired Result

```
      LineNum Warehouse           GeneralDescription
0     2                         
1     3       General Liability   General Liability
2     4       WRS                 WRS
3     5       WRS                 WRS
4     6       CENTRAL             
5     7       General Liability   General Liability
6     8       CENTRAL             
7     9       wrs                 WRS
8    10       WRS                 WRS
9    11       GENERAL LIABILITY   General Liability
10   12       General Liability   General Liability
```

Comment: Here's a good example of how to write a _good, meaningful, searchable_ title. Do take a look at my edit. Good naming sense is important, because there are many like you who'll have this problem and they'll need to be able to find answers to their questions easily. :)

Comment: thanks that is extremely helpful my friend. I have just recently started using stackoverflow and feel my question phrasing ability is one of my weaker skills. I am quickly finding out that there is a very specific way to ask questions on this site. I am slowly learning. I appreciate the communitie's patience and help.

Comment: Thanks, we appreciate you asking good, answerable questions with clear explanation and copy-passable examples. Keep em coming!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can normalize your column by case using `str.title` and then use `value_counts` + `map` to create a mask.

```
i = df1.Warehouse.replace('Empty', np.nan).str.title()
df1['GeneralDescription'] = df1.Warehouse.where(i.map(i.value_counts()).gt(3))
```

```
print(df1)
    LineNum          Warehouse GeneralDescription
0         2              Empty                NaN
1         3  General Liability  General Liability
2         4                WRS                WRS
3         5                WRS                WRS
4         6            CENTRAL                NaN
5         7  General Liability  General Liability
6         8            CENTRAL                NaN
7         9                wrs                wrs
8        10                WRS                WRS
9        11  GENERAL LIABILITY  GENERAL LIABILITY
10       12  General Liability  General Liability
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`pd.Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with [`pd.DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html). We can align similar strings using [`pd.Series.str.lower`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.lower.html).

```
wh_lower = df['Warehouse'].str.lower()
counts = wh_lower.value_counts()

df.loc[wh_lower.map(counts) > 3, 'GeneralDescription'] = df['Warehouse']

print(df)

    LineNum         Warehouse GeneralDescription
0         2             Empty                   
1         3  GeneralLiability   GeneralLiability
2         4               WRS                WRS
3         5               WRS                WRS
4         6           CENTRAL                   
5         7  GeneralLiability   GeneralLiability
6         8           CENTRAL                   
7         9               wrs                wrs
8        10               WRS                WRS
9        11  GENERALLIABILITY   GENERALLIABILITY
10       12  GeneralLiability   GeneralLiability
```

Answer (score 3):

You can using `transform`

```
df.Warehouse=df.Warehouse.str.upper()
df.loc[df.groupby('Warehouse').Warehouse.transform('count').gt(3),'GeneralDescription']=df.Warehouse
df
Out[356]: 
    LineNum         Warehouse GeneralDescription
0         2             EMPTY              Empty
1         3  GENERALLIABILITY   GENERALLIABILITY
2         4               WRS                WRS
3         5               WRS                WRS
4         6           CENTRAL              Empty
5         7  GENERALLIABILITY   GENERALLIABILITY
6         8           CENTRAL              Empty
7         9               WRS                WRS
8        10               WRS                WRS
9        11  GENERALLIABILITY   GENERALLIABILITY
10       12  GENERALLIABILITY   GENERALLIABILITY
```

Comment: Am I missing something or is there a missing space between "general" and "liability"?

Comment: @coldspeed, I got rid of the space to help copy + paste. Shouldn't be relevant to solution though :)

Comment: @jpp yes, of course. Was just rubbing my eyes trying to see if I'd missed something.

Comment: @jpp I am doing the same thing:-)